# AutoSuggest in a asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to auto suggest in a text box in a asp.net page. I want to display names of the users from the user table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [Ajax autocompelete](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) for Jquery or create your own web service that return users names from your database and call this service using javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067242/autosuggest-in-a-asp-net-using-ajax-controls

Answer (score 3):

You can use AJAX Control Toolkit AutoComplete Control. You can see more about it here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067242/autosuggest-in-a-asp-net-using-ajax-controls

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX Control Toolkit AutoComplete Control.http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067242/autosuggest-in-a-asp-net-using-ajax-controls