# AutoSuggest in a asp.net using Ajax controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to do auto suggest in a `TextBox` and I used `Ajax` controls to do so. I am giving movies array some values. I want to give that value from the database by filtering the user table with the email Id that the User used to Login to the website. I am not able to call the Label value into the method below. I have stored the email id of user in label during page load. help me to do that.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(),System.Web.UI.WebControls, System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
   // Create array of movies
    string[] movies = {"Joey", "Joester", "Joker", "Joeic", "Joic", "Shrek II"};

    // Return matching movies
    return (from m in movies where m.StartsWith(prefixText,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) select m).Take(count).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the AJAX Control Toolkit you can see example [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).

I am not sure what is the label about, but you need to set `UseContextKey=true;` and specify the context key for the `ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender`

In your case you can add the following code to Page.Load:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  AutoCompleteExtenderID.ContextKey = LabeWtihEmal.Text;
}
```

Comment: Label stores the Email id of the user who logs into the system. I need that value to retrieve values in database

Answer (score 0):

It's because the web method is static. On the load of your page, set the context key for your AutoCompleteExtender to the label value (email id).  Also, make sure that UseContextKey is set to true.